# Broadcasting ip:port by socket server

Tags: sockets, networking, network-protocols

I'm trying to find a way for client to know socket server ip:port, without explicitly defining it. Generally I have a socket server running on portable device that's connect to network over DHCP (via WiFi), and ideally clients should be able to find it automaticaly.

So I guess a question is whether socket server can somehow broadcast it's address over local network? I think UPnP can do this, but I'd rather not get into it.

I'm quite sure that this question was asked on Stack lot's of times, but I could find proper keywords to search for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method of doing this is via UDP broadcast packets. See [beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#broadcast) if you're using BSD sockets. And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1.aspx) is Microsoft's version of the same.

Assuming all the clients of the application are on the same side of a router then a broadcast address of `255.255.255.255` (or `ff02::1` for IPv6) should be more than adequate.

Multicast is another option, but if this is a LAN-only thing I don't think that's necessary.

### Suggestion

Pick a UDP port number (say for the sake of an example we pick 1667). The client should listen to UDP messages on `255.255.255.255:1667` (or whatever the equivalent is. e.g.: `IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1667)`). The server should broadcast messages on the same address.

### Format Suggestion

UDP Packet: First four bytes as a magic number, next four bytes an IPv4 address (and you might want to add other things like a server name).

The magic number is just in case there is a collision with another application using the same port. Check both the length of the packet and the magic number.

Server would broadcast the packet at something like 30 second time intervals. (Alternatively you could have the server send a response only when a client sends a request via broadcast.)

Comment: Rather than having the server broadcast its info at frequent intervals, which just wastes bandwidth, a commonly used option is to have the client send its own broadcast instead, asking for any servers to identify themselves.  Any server receiving that broadcast can then send a reply back containing its current info.  The client can gather that info and pick which server (if multiple) to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

Some options are:

- [DNS-SD](http://www.dns-sd.org/) (which seems to translate to "Apple Bonjour"): it has libraries on macOS, but it needs to install the Bonjour service on Windows. I don't know the Linux situation for this. So, it's multi-platform but you need external libraries.
- UDP broadcast or multicast
- Some other fancy things like Ethernet broadcast, raw sockets, ...

For your case (clients on a WiFi network), a UDP broadcast packet would suffice, it's multi-platform, and not too difficult to implement from the ground up.

Choosing this option, the two main algorithms are:

1. The server(s) send an "announce" broadcast packet, with clients listening to the broadcast address. Once clients receive the "announce" packet, they know about the server address. Now they can send UDP packets to the server (which will discover their addresses for sending a reply), or connect using TCP.
2. The client(s) send a "discover" broadcast packet, with the server(s) listening to the broadcast address. Once the server(s) receive the "discover" packet, it can reply directly to it with an "announce" UDP packet.

One or the other could be better for your application, it depends.

### Please consider these arguments:

- Servers usually listen to requests and send replies
- A server that sends regular "announce" broadcast packets over a WiFi network, for a client that may arrive or not, wastes the network bandwidth, while a client knows exactly when it needs to poll for available servers, and stop once it's done.

---

As a mix of the two options, a server could send a "gratuitous announce" broadcast packet once it comes up, and then it can listen for "discover" broadcast requests from clients, replying directly to one of them using a regular UDP packet.

From here, the client can proceed as needed: send direct requests with UDP to the server, connect to a TCP address:port provided in the "announce" packet, ...

(this is the scheme I used in an application I am working on)