# Does the server wait for a response from the client when using server sent events?

Tags: server-sent-events

SSEs are advertised as a unidirectional communication tool to be used from server to client. I have a requirement to broadcast data to all clients and so i was wondering how SSEs behave on a low level. I cannot seem to find any low level information about SSEs online.

Primarily i would like to know if, after sending the data, does the server wait for a response from the client to confirm it has received the data before finishing the "send". That would mean that doing a broadcast using a for loop would be quiet dangerous and slow in which case websockets might be the better options.

Perhaps the implementation depends entirely on the language and framework? Is it not standardized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSE and WebSockets are both over TCP, so there could be a wait before the socket could be used to send further data.

However, each client is a dedicated socket. So server-side you would be using threads or async coding (depending on the server-side language and its conventions). So looping through all the sockets to send a message to each client would be fine and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast usually uses UDP which does not wait for a response.  - - [Broadcasting ip:port by socket server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664109/broadcasting-ipport-by-socket-server)
.. says

UDP Packet: First four bytes as a magic number, next four bytes an IPv4 address (and you might want to add other things like a server name).

The magic number is just in case there is a collision with another application using the same port. Check both the length of the packet and the magic number.

**Server would broadcast the packet at something like 30 second time intervals. (Alternatively you could have the server send a response only when a client sends a request via broadcast.**)

So the client app would have to send a request back to the server app.

Different protocols would get different responses according the the underlying technology. eg HTTP uses responses extnsivly.

Comment: ah, i see i am simply using the wrong terminology. Broadcasting is a concept only applicable to UDP since it doesnt wait for a response and since http is built on TCP therefore there is no concept of broadcasting and in fact i suspect both SSEs and websockets would have this same problem of having to wait for one client to finish before sending another and therefore this problem is a parallel async IO problem. Thank you for the clarification.